# Is it possible to solve this recurrence relation of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

We know that $p_1(x) = 0$ and $p_2(x) = x^2 - 1$.
The recurrence is given by

$$
p_n(x) = xp_{n-1}(x) - p_{n-2}(x).
$$

Is there a way to find a general formula for $p_n(x)$ that does not depend on the previous terms?

Comment: Yes, follow the methods [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321427/the-polynomials-p-n-x-are-defined-by-p-0-x-0-p-1-x-x-and-p-n-x).

Comment: For $n \ge 2$, $p_n(x) = (x^2-1)U_{n-2}(x/2)$ where $U_n(x)$ is the [Chebyshev polynomial of second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Second_kindChebyshev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can consider a solution of the difference equation in the for $p_{n}(x) = r^{n}(x)$ and determine that $r^{2} - x \, r + 1 = 0$ and has solutions $\{\alpha(x), \beta(x)\}$, where $2 \, \alpha(x) = x + \sqrt{x^2 - 4}$ and $2 \, \beta(x) = x - \sqrt{x^2 - 4}$. Now a solution for $p_{n}(x)$ takes the form
$$p_{n}(x) = A \, \alpha^{n}(x) + B \, \beta^{n}(x).$$
Since $p_{1}(x) = 0$ then $B = - A (\alpha/\beta)$, or
$$p_{n}(x) = \alpha(x) \, A \, \left( \alpha^{n-1}(x) - \beta^{n-1}(x) \right).$$
Since $p_{2}(x) = x^{2} - 1$ then
$$p_{n}(x) = (x^{2} - 1) \, \left( \frac{\alpha^{n-1}(x) - \beta^{n-1}(x)}{\alpha(x) - \beta(x)} \right).$$

A generating function may be obtained for which
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_{n}(x) \, t^{n} = \frac{(x^{2}-1) \, t^{2}}{1-x t + t^{2}}.$$
Further properties may be obtained by use of the generating function.